# Google Billing Library : QueryPurchasesAsync : Subscription resource of cancelled purchase not returned

Tags: java, android, in-app-subscription, play-billing-library

I am working on integrating Google Billing Library into my application for making purchases from my app. I have created a 1-month test subscription from the application. Every time a subscription is auto-renewed, a subscription resource is returned then i am using the value of "IsAutorenewing"  for processing of the purchase in my app

After few renewals of the existing subscription, i have cancelled the subscription and tried to query the purchases using querypurchasesasync but this time the subscription resource is not returned after the subscription is cancelled to check the value of IsAutoRenewing

Can you please suggest why cancelled purchase is not returned & what needs to be done in order to get the cancelled purchase also?